# .gitignore when developing Python and Django Applications on Windows

Tags: python, django, git, visual-studio, ptvs

What should I change in my `.gitignore` file when I'm developing Python/Django applications using PTVS, naturally, on Windows?

Answer (score 6):

GitHub has a nice [collection of `.gitignore` templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore). When I start a Django project I grab the [Python template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) and add to it as needed.

I don't develop on Windows, but they also have a [Visual Studio template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). You could grab both and merge them as needed.

I doubt these GitHub links are gonna die anytime soon, but I'll add the current contents of these files anyway.

**[`Python.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)**

> ```
> # Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
> __pycache__/
> *.py[cod]
> *$py.class
>
> # C extensions
> *.so
>
> # Distribution / packaging
> .Python
> env/
> build/
> develop-eggs/
> dist/
> downloads/
> eggs/
> .eggs/
> lib/
> lib64/
> parts/
> sdist/
> var/
> *.egg-info/
> .installed.cfg
> *.egg
>
> # PyInstaller
> #  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
> #  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
> *.manifest
> *.spec
>
> # Installer logs
> pip-log.txt
> pip-delete-this-directory.txt
>
> # Unit test / coverage reports
> htmlcov/
> .tox/
> .coverage
> .coverage.*
> .cache
> nosetests.xml
> coverage.xml
> *,cover
>
> # Translations
> *.mo
> *.pot
>
> # Django stuff:
> *.log
>
> # Sphinx documentation
> docs/_build/
>
> # PyBuilder
> target/
> ```

**[`VisualStudio.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)**

> ```
> ## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
> ## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
>
> # User-specific files
> *.suo
> *.user
> *.userosscache
> *.sln.docstates
>
> # User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
> *.userprefs
>
> # Build results
> [Dd]ebug/
> [Dd]ebugPublic/
> [Rr]elease/
> [Rr]eleases/
> x64/
> x86/
> build/
> bld/
> [Bb]in/
> [Oo]bj/
>
> # Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
> .vs/
>
> # MSTest test Results
> [Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
> [Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
>
> # NUNIT
> *.VisualState.xml
> TestResult.xml
>
> # Build Results of an ATL Project
> [Dd]ebugPS/
> [Rr]eleasePS/
> dlldata.c
>
> # DNX
> project.lock.json
> artifacts/
>
> *_i.c
> *_p.c
> *_i.h
> *.ilk
> *.meta
> *.obj
> *.pch
> *.pdb
> *.pgc
> *.pgd
> *.rsp
> *.sbr
> *.tlb
> *.tli
> *.tlh
> *.tmp
> *.tmp_proj
> *.log
> *.vspscc
> *.vssscc
> .builds
> *.pidb
> *.svclog
> *.scc
>
> # Chutzpah Test files
> _Chutzpah*
>
> # Visual C++ cache files
> ipch/
> *.aps
> *.ncb
> *.opensdf
> *.sdf
> *.cachefile
>
> # Visual Studio profiler
> *.psess
> *.vsp
> *.vspx
>
> # TFS 2012 Local Workspace
> $tf/
>
> # Guidance Automation Toolkit
> *.gpState
>
> # ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
> _ReSharper*/
> *.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
> *.DotSettings.user
>
> # JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
> .JustCode
>
> # TeamCity is a build add-in
> _TeamCity*
>
> # DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
> *.dotCover
>
> # NCrunch
> _NCrunch_*
> .*crunch*.local.xml
>
> # MightyMoose
> *.mm.*
> AutoTest.Net/
>
> # Web workbench (sass)
> .sass-cache/
>
> # Installshield output folder
> [Ee]xpress/
>
> # DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
> DocProject/buildhelp/
> DocProject/Help/*.HxT
> DocProject/Help/*.HxC
> DocProject/Help/*.hhc
> DocProject/Help/*.hhk
> DocProject/Help/*.hhp
> DocProject/Help/Html2
> DocProject/Help/html
>
> # Click-Once directory
> publish/
>
> # Publish Web Output
> *.[Pp]ublish.xml
> *.azurePubxml
> # TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings 
> # but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
> *.pubxml
> *.publishproj
>
> # NuGet Packages
> *.nupkg
> # The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
> **/packages/*
> # except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
> !**/packages/build/
> # Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
> #!**/packages/repositories.config
>
> # Windows Azure Build Output
> csx/
> *.build.csdef
>
> # Windows Store app package directory
> AppPackages/
>
> # Visual Studio cache files
> # files ending in .cache can be ignored
> *.[Cc]ache
> # but keep track of directories ending in .cache
> !*.[Cc]ache/
>
> # Others
> ClientBin/
> [Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
> ~$*
> *~
> *.dbmdl
> *.dbproj.schemaview
> *.pfx
> *.publishsettings
> node_modules/
> orleans.codegen.cs
>
> # RIA/Silverlight projects
> Generated_Code/
>
> # Backup & report files from converting an old project file
> # to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
> # because we have git ;-)
> _UpgradeReport_Files/
> Backup*/
> UpgradeLog*.XML
> UpgradeLog*.htm
>
> # SQL Server files
> *.mdf
> *.ldf
>
> # Business Intelligence projects
> *.rdl.data
> *.bim.layout
> *.bim_*.settings
>
> # Microsoft Fakes
> FakesAssemblies/
>
> # Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
> .ntvs_analysis.dat
>
> # Visual Studio 6 build log
> *.plg
>
> # Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
> *.opt
> ```